# laravel jquery post, posted variable empty

Tags: jquery, laravel

For my website i am trying to use laravel, and want to do a 
jquery post and send some data.

my js

```
$.post(
    '/ajax/index',

    {
        prijs : "321"
    },  
    function()
    {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

    }
);
```

my route

```
Route::get('ajax/index', 'AjaxController@index');
```

my controller function

```
public function index()
{
    $prijs = Input::get('prijs');
    echo $prijs." = de prijs";
}
```

what happens if i run the post.

the alert runs with the message:
= de prijs ( so i know the function is called)

but there is no value where $prijs used to be.
why is $prijs empty, and how can i get access to the prijs data (321) send by the $.post.

**note
if i change my route to post the alert gives a methodnotallowedexception, i dont understand why it works with get (i get a response).**

Comment: Try naming your route.  `Route::post('ajax/index', array('uses' => 'AjaxController@index', 'as' => 'ajax.route'));` and in jquery use `$.post({{ URL::route('ajax.route') }},...)};`.  Also in your jquery function, you need to pass in `data` and `status` for them variables to be available.

Comment: @user3158900 prijs: "321" is the data right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ajax call is sending the data via POST

Your Laravel index method is looking for a GET value. Try this instead:

```
 $data = Input::all();
 echo $data['prijs']." = de prijs";
```

Also make sure your route is doing a POST not a GET.

If you need a more in depth example look here: http://laravel.io/bin/k4M2e

Comment: if i change my route to post i get a  methodnotallowedexception

Comment: If you leave it as a GET in your routes, and change the Input as shown here, what happens?

Comment: undefined index prijs

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your route be a POST

```
Route::post('ajax/index', 'AjaxController@index');
```

Comment: thats what i thougt, if i change it to post i get a methodnotallowedexception

Answer (score 0):

**Your route should be:** (since you're `posting`)

```
Route::post('ajax/index', 'AjaxController@index');
```

**Your method needs to return something:**

```
public function index()
{
    $prijs = Input::get('prijs');

    return Response::json($prijs." = de prijs");
}
```